# SQL Azure Data Sync - How to acces API for Data Sync?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, azure, synchronization, azure-sql-database

I am new to Azure Data Sync.

I want to trigger ***sync*** from code. Basically, I want ***Sync Now*** for particular Sync Groups from the application.

Is there any API for Azure Data Sync similar to Blog, Queue? I could not find sample code or example.

I read few articles about SqlAzureSyncProvider. Am I in the right direct?

Thank in advance![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Azure Data Sync Service has no publicly available API as of the current release. So you cannot programmatically invoke the sync as of now. It's in the plans though, see: [SQL Azure Data Sync Feature Voting](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/44459-sql-azure-data-sync-feature-voting)

Answer (score 0):

There is no api as JuneT mentioned. if you want you can create custom solution using Microsoft sync framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code provided by microsoft.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-Sync-Service-60293622
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1568.walkthrough-of-windows-azure-sync-service-sample.aspx#Your_Scenario

but you need to implment your own code for synchronization